# Replacing default Google Analytics with Google Measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

We're considering ditching the default Google Analytics implementation with the Google Measurement protocol. Our main concern here is to have less external scripts on our site and increase the performance.

Does anybody have experience in making this switch? What can we expect in loss of data like campaign and/or Adwords tracking?

Thanks!

Comment: this definitely sounds like reinventing the wheel. you'll have to recreate all the logic of handling referrers, client ids and other staff. analytics.js is quite a tiny library with a subtle performance load. so switching from this to custom implementation wouldn't probably worth the effort

Comment: Thanks, we'll probably reconsider it

Comment: One other thing to consider if you will not be able to retarget these people via audiences if you only use server side tracking as there won't be a cookie that the Googleverse can understand and link to something it knows